# Problems using Rotativa to generate a pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, rotativa

i'm using   Rotativa  to generate a pdf from view

my controller  :

```
    public ActionResult DetailsCandidat(Candidat candidat,int id = 0)
    {

        candidat = _db.Candidats.Find(id);

        return View(candidat);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DetailsCandidat(Candidat candidat)
    {



        return new ViewAsPdf(candidat);

    }
```

the  problem  that  in   GET  action   i  display  some  data  (from candidat model )

when  the  pdf is  generated  the  data  is disappearing

i got just  the  html  form

Edit  :  Answer

i  found  a solution   it's simple

i had to change the Post Action to  :

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DetailsCandidat(int id)
    {

        var candidat = _db.Candidats.Find(id);

        return new ViewAsPdf(candidat);

    }
```